# Does mongod run in a single thread when performing a mongorestore?

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

When monitoring a mongodb restore, I'm tracking two processes...

```
CPU   COMMAND
100%  mongod --config /etc/mongo/mongod.conf
0%    mongorestore /data/dump
```

MongoDB is 4.4.14 and mongorestore is version is 100.5.3.  I'm running it inside a docker container.

I never see mongod go past 100%.. Is there a way to allow it to use more than a single core when performing a mongo restore?

Answer (score 1):

By default mongorestore will restore max 4x collections in paralel with single insertionWorkerPerCollection( Since you see only two processes running in paralel , perhaps you have only 2x collections in your database... ) , but you can increase this parameters if you have more collections and would like to restore faster , check the official docs for details:

[--numParalelCollections](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongorestore/#std-option-mongorestore.--numParallelCollections)   ( default=4 )

Number of collections mongorestore should restore in parallel.

[--numInsertionWorkersPerCollection](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongorestore/#std-option-mongorestore.--numInsertionWorkersPerCollection) ( default=1 )

Specifies the number of insertion workers to run concurrently per collection.
For large imports, increasing the number of insertion workers may increase the speed of the import.